# Non-null string in Hive array

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Assuming a source table with structure:

```
personid INT, 
name STRING,
mobilephone STRING,
homephone STRING
```

and target table structure:

```
personid INT, 
telephone ARRAY<STRING>
```

To insert into target from source, I did

```
select 
personid,
array(mobilephone, homephone)
from source_table

12, ["+1958523366","+1258523366"]
13, ["+1958523366",""]
```

Second row in result shows empty string because `homephone` is null in source table. How to return something like this instead:

```
12, ["+1958523366","+1258523366"]
13, ["+1958523366"]
```

i.e. return item in array only if not null

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
personid,
split(concat_ws(',',mobilephone,homephone),',')
from source_table
```